# What is the current exchange rate of/for

Tags: prepositions

Are the prepositions used naturally in the following? Someone says b feels more natural than c.

> a. What is the current exchange rate **for** the US dollar?

> b. What is the current exchange rate **of** the US dollar to the Japanese yen?

> c. What is the current exchange rate **for** the US dollar to the Japanese yen?

Comment: They all sound correct and natural to me. Is there something in particular you're after?

Comment: Someone says b feels more natural than a.

Comment: There's two differences between the two, so it's difficult to compare them. If you're interested in how natural they are, why don't you ask that instead of whether they're correct?

Comment: I made a mistake. I should have said, "Someone says b feels more natural than c."

Comment: Post edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: Where does this someone come from? US? UK? Australia? Please provide the link to where you have had this conversation.